# Android: Achieving smooth roll of ball using accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer

I have developed a maze game for Android where you control the ball by tilting the phone.

So I use the accelerometer and integrate the x and y accelerometer values and then move the ball a step in that direction.

I have a  problem though, I cannot achieve a very smooth roll. When the ball picks up speed it is to obvious that it jumps in big discrete steps. I have seen other apps like this where the ball rolls fast but smoothly.

So I might have to change my strategy, use some sort of time solution instead. Now the faster the speed the bigger the step I move. Instead maybe I should have a timer that moves the ball 1 pixel every ms if speed is high or only every 10th ms if the speed is low or something along those lines. 
Or how do people achieve a smoother roll?

Also: Would you use OpenGL for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're really doing here is integrating coupled differential equations.  Don't worry if you haven't taken enough calculus or physics to know what that means.

People who integrate coupled differential equations for a living have evolved many algorithms to do so efficiently.

You really have four equations here: acceleration in x- and y-directions and velocity in x- and y-directions:

```
dvx/dt = ax
dvy/dt = ax
dsx/dt = vx
dxy/dt = vy
```

(sx, sy) give the position of the ball at a given time.  You'll need initial conditions for (sx, sy) and (vx, vy).

It sounds like you've chosen the simplest way to integration ODEs: Euler explicit integration.  You calculate the values at the end of a step from the values at the beginning plus the rate of change times the time step:

```
(vx, vy)_1 = (vx, vy)_0 + (ax, ay)_0 * dt
(sx, sy)_1 = (sx, sy)_0 + (vx, vy)_0 * dt
```

It's easy to program, but it tends to suffer from stability problems under certain conditions if your time step is too large.

You can shrink your time step, which will force you to perform the calculations many more times, or switch to another integration scheme.  Search for implicit integration, Runge-Kutta, etc.

Integration and rendering are separate problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would it make sense to calculate speed and update screen separately then? Have the sensorthread update the speed then have a timer that updates the screen every ms or so.

Comment: I think you should update velocity and position and perform screen rendering at the same time, in the same thread.  You want to use dynamic accelerometer data, so you can't precalculate the paths.

Comment: Actually what I did was to just calculate the integral for each direction separately. Just performing a line integral. Subtract the current time and the time at last step and then calculate the area under the line between the acceleration values. Then add that to a sum which is the speed. I still don't see how your tip (although informative) solves the real problem here, when speeds gets high I move a lot of steps on the screen which results in that if you move the ball in a circle it becomes a multicorner "circle" if that makes sense.

Comment: It does if you understand something about numerical integration.  Extrapolation is a dangerous thing, especially when you're predicting the value at the end of a long step based on a slope that's in force at the beginning of the step.  Your accuracy at the end depends on a small change in the slope over the step.  If it's large, you're better off solving it iteratively: guessing the slope at the end, calculating a new ending value, seeing how good your guess was.

Comment: How does the fact they are coupled affect the calculation? i found this but I am not sure it can be used if they are coupled: https://java.net/projects/cougarsquared/sources/svn/content/trunk/core/libraries/flanagan/integration/RungeKutta.java?rev=2236

Comment: You can't solve for displacement until you have velocity.  The sequence is determined.

Comment: I started this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922524/android-java-calculating-coupled-differential-equations-effectively. Should I solve 2 diff equations separately with Runge Kutta then just do xPos += xSpeed; and yPos += ySpeed; ?